# how to fill color cells with 2 percentage data from other cells

Tags: python, excel, pandas, excel-formula, xlsxwriter

I have 3 cells for example:
A1: has an independent value
B1: has a percentage value of %30
B2: has a percentage value of %70

What i want to do is, filling A1 cell background with 2 colors (yellow/green). Yellow needs to be at %30 from left and green needs to be %70 from right so i can understand by looking A1 that my percentage ratio is %30 by %70 except i don't know how to do it and apparently even google

All of the values are coming from a python script using pandas module and writing as an excel file via xlsxwriter

Comment: Posting some code would help a lot... How is working right now?

Comment: Maybe think about using gradient fills (.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops) using the values in the cells to define the stop points. I haven't done it before personally, just a thought.

Comment: i don't have a code about the issue i just want to achieve that but cannot find a way to start. Right now my code is running some SQL queries and writes the results in a way i programmed nothing complicated.

Comment: Depending on the level of accuracy you are after the gradient colorstops works pretty well. I just tested it with 10 points and looks ok. Try starting with recording the macro for setting the background colors in the a cell, you should get two points 0 and 1, just play with this and say do 10 points, so for the 30% component do 0, 0.1, 0.2 and 0.3 with the yellow and the remaining with green. From there work out your resolution (number of points) and wrap it all up in some code to reference your value cells.

Comment: Did you look at conditional formatting: http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html ?

It would also help if you can share an example data, which rows you want to be yellow or green etc. Then I can answer with some code.

Comment: @burhan yes but it doesn't have the solution. It's what excel has on its conditional formatting

Comment: @fuzunspm I don't know what you mean.  Why conditional formatting doesn't work for you?

Comment: @burhan did you read and understand my question?